# How to handle body onload event in <head> tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, sitemesh

I am using sitemesh in our application. In decorator jsp I have added `<decorator:head>` in head and on body tag:

```
<body onload="<decorator:getProperty property='body.onload'/>" >
```

So I want to handle body `onload` on my jsp page.
I have added following things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        alert("hi");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:init();">
```

But `init()` does not worked in my jsp page.

Comment: Don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in inline event handler attributes; you're merely adding a useless JavaScript label there. Moreover, this should work as expected, what exactly “does not work”?

Comment: @Narcel: On body onload i want perform some layout issue for different resolution.  one div consist of jquery component when we specify height in percentage it does not work. so for this on body onload i m specifying height in Pixel. but body onload does not work on jsp page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        alert("hi");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not just stick it all into the `script` element? Much cleaner than mucking about with element attributes:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('hi');
};
```

Or, alternatively, keeping the `init` declaration:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. On body onload event i want to handle some layout issue. on window.onload event some flickering issue is occur.

Comment: @amit: the `onload` attribute of the `body` element is the same as `window.onload`

Comment: you might wish to use `document.onreadystatechange=init;` but it is a bit more complex -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957(v=vs.85).aspx the difference is that *window.onload* fires when all the linked elements in the document are loaded while *document.onreadystatechange* fires when the html part is loaded and do not wait for the images

Comment: @Venimus: thanks for reply. but where should i put document.onreadystatechange=init in my jsp page. means  whether in head tag or outside head tag?